# is there a solution to solve "Someone allocated physical memory at VA 0x400000...0 without creating a VMA"?

Tags: c++, c, riscv, gem5

I'm trying to use cross-compiler to compile a c file to a RISCV executable program which is simply to print the thread id.
the program uses pthrad.h and print the thread id in a for circle. there are just simply thread_creat(), thread_deatch()
I use gcc to complie the file to a X86 program and it runs well.
However, when I use riscv-linux-gnu-gcc to compile the file to a RISCV program and the gem5 where the program runs will report the error as follows
[image]
So I tried to use --debug-flags= to make clear where it goes wrong, but I get a message that I can't understand
[image]
for this, I have checked there is a ld.so.cache file in my linux system.
Though I know what is VMA, there is not document or hint telling me how to manage this problem such as how to creat VMA in gem5.
I hope to reap some help from you.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about this error, please also ask on mailing list. In the future, please copy paste text from the terminal instead of using images.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will pay attention to it in the future.